# How to fix 'FileNotFoundError' in a pre-written file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to set up GPT-2 encoding using the following tutorial:

```
https://medium.com/@ngwaifoong92/beginners-guide-to-retrain-gpt-2-117m-to-generate-custom-text-content-8bb5363d8b7f
```

I am trying to enter

```
python encode.py giselle.txt giselle.npz
```

in the command prompt but it keeps giving me a FileNotFoundError for an encoder.json file that is already in the path it tries to retrieve it from.
How may I go about fixing this?

I have tried editing the encode.py file to specify the exact path to the encoder.json file but it still gives FileNotFoundError

```
def get_encoder(model_name):
    with open(os.path.join('models', model_name, 'encoder.json'), 'r') as f:
        encoder = json.load(f)
    with open(os.path.join('models', model_name, 'vocab.bpe'), 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        bpe_data = f.read()
```

I expected the giselle.txt to be encoded to the giselle.npz file but all that is sent in the command prompt is

```
 File "C:\projectgiselle\gpt-2-finetuning\src\encoder.py", line 109, in get_encoder
    with open(os.path.join('models', model_name, 'encoder.json'), 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'models\\117M\\encoder.json'
```

Comment: Where is `encoder.json` located?

Comment: @skymon the encoder.json file is located in the following path `C:\projectgiselle\gpt-2-finetuning\models\117M`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error!

The tutorial is geared towards Windows users and has you copy train.py and encode.py into the /src/ directory for 'simplicity', so that you don't have to modify the PYTHONPATH. But moving these might violate the code's expectations of where certain scripts are. The solution is simply to move the expect files (encoder.json) correspondingly.

I was able to successfully continue the tutorial by copying and pasting the entire /model/ folder into /src/, so that /src/model/. Then you can run encode.py from /src/ as it instructs.